# Passing data to DataProvider from Excel sheet- Getting Exception - java.lang.RuntimeException and java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

Below code is for submitting the flight details and multiple rows are getting fetched from the `Excel` and Multiple Rows are getting passed to `DataProvider` from `ExcelSheet`. 
`'VerifyInvalidLogin'` is getting skipped and throwing

```
Exceptions java.lang.RuntimeException and java.lang.NullPointerException
```

while passing the data from `Excel` sheet

```
package phptravels;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class FlightBooking {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;
    String appURL="http://phptravels.net";
    //locators
    private By from_Location = By.id("flights_search_from_location_name");
    private By to_Location = By.id("flights_search_to_location_name");
    private By fromDate = By.id("flights_search_outbound_date");
    private By toDate = By.id("flights_search_inbound_date");
    private By cabinClass = By.id("flights_search_cabin_class");
    private By adult = By.id("flights_search_num_adults");
    private By child = By.id("flights_search_num_children");
    private By bySubmit = By.id("flights_search_num_children");
    //WorkBook initialization
    public static HSSFWorkbook WBook = null;
    public static HSSFSheet WSheet= null;
    public static HSSFRow Row;
    public static HSSFCell cell;
    //Opening Firefox
    @BeforeClass
    public void testSetUp(){
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
    }
    //Data Provide Test
    @Test(dataProvider="FlightBooking")
        public void VerifyInvalidLogin(String frmloc, String toloc, String Datefrom, String Dateto, String Cabin, String Adult, String Child ) {
            driver.navigate().to(appURL);
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Account")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("new@gmail.com");
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Usha@moti");
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).submit();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Flights")).click();

            /*Switching to ifram*/
            WebElement frame=driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
            driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
            driver.findElement(from_Location).sendKeys(frmloc);
            driver.findElement(to_Location).sendKeys(toloc);
            driver.findElement(fromDate).sendKeys(Datefrom);
            driver.findElement(toDate).sendKeys(Dateto);
            driver.findElement(cabinClass).sendKeys(Cabin);
            driver.findElement(adult).sendKeys(Adult);
            driver.findElement(child).sendKeys(Child);
            //wait for element to be visible and perform click
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(bySubmit));
            driver.findElement(bySubmit).click();
            }
    //Data Provide returning arrayobject
    @DataProvider(name="FlightBooking")
    public Object[][] loginData() throws IOException{
        Object[][] arrayObject = getExcelData("D://Users//priya_v//phptravels.com//Flight.xls","Sheet1");
        return arrayObject;

    }
    @Test
    //getExcelData() method
    private String[][] getExcelData(String fileName, String sheetName) throws IOException {
        String[][] arrayExcelData = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            HSSFWorkbook WBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            HSSFSheet WSheet = WBook.getSheet(sheetName); 

            int totalNoOfRows = WSheet.getLastRowNum();
            System.out.println(totalNoOfRows);
            int totalNoOfCols=WSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            System.out.println(totalNoOfCols);

            arrayExcelData = new String[totalNoOfRows-1][totalNoOfCols];

            for (int i= 1 ; i < totalNoOfRows; i++) {

                for (int j=0; j < totalNoOfCols; j++) {
                    arrayExcelData[i-1][j] = getCellData(sheetName,i,j);
                }
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arrayExcelData;
    }
    //getCellData method
    @Test
        public static String getCellData(String Sheet, int row, int col){

                int index = WBook.getSheetIndex(Sheet);
                WSheet = WBook.getSheetAt(index);
                Row = WSheet.getRow(row);
                if (Row == null)
                return "";
                cell = Row.getCell(col);
                if (cell == null)
                return "";

                switch (cell.getCellType())
                {
                case  Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                return cell.getStringCellValue();               

                case  Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());          

                case  Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                return "";      

                case  Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                return cell.getStringCellValue();           

                case  Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                return String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());          

                default:
                return "Cell not found";        

                }


    }
     @Test
        public void tearDown() {
            driver.quit();
        }
}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace if possible.

Comment: You have some issues in your class: `getExcelData` are `getCellData` utils and not tests. `tearDown` should be `@AfterClass` and not a test. It is recommended that data providers like `VerifyInvalidLogin` are static.

Comment: Hi @juherr I have done the changes as you said, still VerifyInvalidLogin is getting skipped

Comment: Sure. Changes I pointed are not fixing the issue. If you want help, we need more details like the stacktrace.

Comment: Hi @juherr i have no idea how to get stacktrace information

Comment: The console or the testng report should have it.